# AngularJS file not loading in browser using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, angularjs

i am very new to Eclipse, Spring and AngularJS, This is my first project in Spring and i have referenced AngualarJS and LoginPage.js as below in Eclipse.

[image: Reference given in Eclipse]

But when this application is compiled and Run in Chrome, it throws an error like "server responded with error (resource not found)" as shown below

[image: AngularJS and LoginPage.JS not loaded]

And my Web.xml is as follows
[image: webXml]

Is there any setting in Eclipse which i am missing?. Please note it works fine with VisualStudio or if done in normal folder structure. Only when done through Eclipse we get the issue.

Comment: It's not a front end problem..I think you are using Spring and have you add reference in `web.xml` file...cause your server didn't find the path

Comment: write
`<script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/appScripts/angular.js></script>`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: Thanks for a quick reply and appreciate your knowledge for finding out its Spring framework, But can you please let me know what configuration to add in "web.xml" along with syntax plz.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring WebMVC, you can put a line like this in your context.xml.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This maps your resources folder in WebApp Root (so src/main/webapp/resources) to the /resources/* url. Put your CSS, JS, Images in the Resources folder and then change the  link.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, it was quite simple, i had to place the js file under WebContent folder and not web-inf, and had to give the reference as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="appScripts/angular.js"></script>
```